# adding a row to a DGV bound to a table

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've used the following to add a table to a DataGridView on a WinForm:

```
    void PopulateGridView() {
        conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IMS"].ConnectionString);
        myAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM FrontDesk.dbo.tb_xxx", conn);
        mySet = new DataSet();
        myAdapt.Fill(mySet, "AvailableValues");
        myTable = mySet.Tables["AvailableValues"];

        this.uxChargeBackDataGridView.DataSource = myTable;
        this.uxChargeBackDataGridView.Columns["RefKey"].Visible = false; 
    }
```

There are 5 rows in the table, which has only 2 fields - the field `RefKey` is hidden from the DGV and is the primary key of the underlying table.

Why doesn't the following work? `Add` seems to be the property of the Rows collection of the DGV that is used to add a row:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uxChargeBackDataGridView.Rows.Add(6, "dre");
    }
```

Comment: Try adding a row to the underlying table instead of the view. Refresh the view if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the grid is using a DataTable as a source, you would have to add the row to the table.  The grid *should* automatically reflect that:

```
DataTable table = (DataTable)uxChargeBackDataGridView.DataSource;
DataRow row = table.NewRow();
row[0] = 6;
row[1] = "dre";
table.Rows.Add(row);
```

Use the `NewRow()` function on the data table to get a DataRow object that has the schema used by the data table.

You wouldn't have to create the `table` reference if you moved your `mySet` and `myTable` variable to the form level scope, then you would be able to just use `myTable.Rows.Add(row);` instead.